# How to call Ajax datatables with parameter ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I want to send parameter when clicking a tag to controller but always null.
How can I get parameters when using datatable ajax? Please help me.

My code in controller:

```
public JsonResult Getdata(string isvk)
{
        var orders = from o in db.Orders
                     select o;

        if (isvk == null)
        {
            return Json(new { data = orders }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        switch (isvk)
        {
            case "canceled":
                orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == -1 || o.Status == -2);
                break;

            case "pending":
                orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == 0);
                break;

            case "approved":
                orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == 1);
                break;

            case "delivered":
                orders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Status == 2);
                break;

            default:
                orders = db.Orders;
                break;
        }

        return Json(new { data = orders.ToList() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Tag `<a>` is outside the table:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Cart", new {isvk = "pending" })">peding</a>
```

My Script:

```
var datatable = $("#myTable").DataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("Getdata","Cart")",

    },
    columns: [
        { data: "CodeOrder"},
        { data: "FullName"},
        { data: "Email"},
        { data: "Phone" },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data from DataTables to the server (i.e. to your controller), you use the `data` option of the `ajax` function. So, first of all, add that:

```
ajax: {
  type: "GET",
  url: "@Url.Action("Getdata","Cart")",
  data: function() {
    return dataToSend;
  }
},
```

You declare `dataToSend` as an empty JavaScript object at the start of the `document.ready` function:

```
var dataToSend = {};
```

Here is my simplified version of your `<a>` tag:

```
<a id="linkOne" linkData="pending" href="#">submit</a>
```

Following the `dataToSend` declaration, I added the following click handler for the `<a>` tag:

```
$("a#linkOne").on('click', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var linkDataValue = $( this ).attr( 'linkData' )
  dataToSend = { "linkData": linkDataValue };
  //console.log( dataToSend );
  table.ajax.reload();
});
```

This code extracts the "pending" text from `linkData="pending"` in the `<a>` tag and adds it to the `dataToSend` object.

Finally, I trigger the DataTable ajax call using `reload()`.

In the controller, this data will be received as a standard URL query parameter (because you are using `GET`):

```
linkData=pending
```

So you can access that in the usual way and format your response accordingly.

In your case, you need to replace my `dataToSend` logic with your required logic, for your specific `<a>` tag.

An important point here is that you need to create your `dataToSend` object correctly.

For one value, it is created as this, as in the above example:

```
{ "linkData": "pending" }
```

If you need to send multiple values (e.g. if you are processing a form) then you would build a JavaScript object like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "fieldOne",
    "value": "x"
  },
  {
    "name": "fieldTwo",
    "value": "y"
  }
]
```

In this case, the object is an array of key-pair values.

For simple forms, the JavaScript `serializeArray()` function can assist with that - for example:

```
$( "#formOne" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  dataToSend = $( "#formOne" ).serializeArray();
  //console.log( dataToSend );
  table.ajax.reload();
});
```

**UPDATE**

In case it helps, here is the full HTML page for my test code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Personnel</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<br>
<form id ="formOne">
    <input id="fieldOne" type="text" name="fieldOne"></input>
    <input id="fieldTwo" type="text" name="fieldTwo"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>
<a id="linkOne" linkData="pending" href="#">submit</a>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    var dataToSend = {};

    $( "#formOne" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      dataToSend = $( "#formOne" ).serializeArray();
      //console.log( dataToSend );
      table.ajax.reload();
    });

    $("a#linkOne").on('click', function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      var linkDataValue = $( this ).attr( 'linkData' )
      dataToSend = { linkData: linkDataValue };
      //console.log( dataToSend );
      table.ajax.reload();
    });

    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      ajax: {
        url: "http://localhost:7000/personnel",
        method: "POST",
        data: function( ) {
          return dataToSend;
        },
        dataSrc: ''
      },
      "columns": [
        { "data": "id" },
        { "data": "firstname" },
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "phone" }
      ]

    } );

  } );

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oh, that so cool, I sent the parameter to the controller and the data returned the same parameter, but datatable.ajax.reload did not work.
noti error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: I used breakpoint on both browser and visual, I noticed that datatable.ajax.reload () was called before the parameter sent to the controller.

Comment: Just to check - in my test code, I used this: `var table = $('#example').DataTable( {...});`. It looks like you are using `var datatable` instead. I assume you updated my code samples to account for that.

Comment: I added my full client-side code in case the overall structure helps you.

Comment: I also updated my code, can you check it for me? i tried it, but still not working.

Comment: What do you want this line to select: `var linkDataValue = $(this).data('id');`? Currently it is undefined. `$(this).data('id')` does not select any value.

Comment: Should it be this: `$(this).attr('id')`? That will select the value of the ID: "linkOne".

Comment: I have tried with your code, and my controller side didn't get the parameter. I also changed the parameter on the controller = string linkData but it displayed the same error as above.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to recreate your error. You can use the browser console to see whether the ajax call is sending `isvk=pending` to the server. If it is not appending that to the URL, then I cannot explain that. If it is appending that to the URL,then your server-side code needs to be changed, to extract the query parameter data from the request URL.

Comment: I'm sure it has been appending to the URL.
Can you add controller on the answer? I want to try again with your code.

Comment: Or can you send me your project? I really want to try them.

Comment: Sorry - no. I can't do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me, i will try it again, and find a solution.

Comment: This is crazy, I just lack `dataSrc`, add it, my code worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You're already very close and the snippets you provided are helpful. What you're missing is that you want the data to update *without leaving the page*. Using an anchor tag the way you are will direct you to that page. Also, you controller action is returning a `JsonResult`, which won't return any type of view (but is correct in this case).

You need to add a page event that triggers on clicking the button and refreshes the data source.

There's a few approaches you can take for this, but here's one of them:

```
<button class="filter-datatable" data-url="@Url.Action("Index","Cart", new {isvk = "pending" })">
```

```
// pageScript.js
// jquery, initialization, etc...

$('.filter-datatable').on('click', function() {
    var newSource = $(this).data('url');
    datatable.ajax.url(newSource).load();
}
```

Comment: Ty for help me !
But when I tried your way, it not working and an error occurred  http://datatables.net/tn/1.
I don't know how to fix that, sorry for the first time I used datatables.

Comment: I realized that when I clicked on the button, I couldn't send parameters ("pendding") to Action Getdata, I didn't know how to send parameters when using load data = ajax.

Answer (score 0):

**Update Script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //test
        var dataToSend = {};
        $("a#linkOne").on('click', function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var linkDataValue = $(this).data('id')
            var linkurl = $(this).data('url')
            dataToSend = { isvk: linkDataValue };
            datatable.ajax.reload();
        });
        var datatable = $("#myTable").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("Getdata","Cart")",
                data: function () {
                    return dataToSend;
                }
            },
            columns: [
                { data: "CodeOrder" },
                { data: "FullName" },
                { data: "Email" },
                { data: "Phone" },
                
            ],
          
        });
    });
```

tag `<a>`:

```
<a id="linkOne" data-id="pending" href="#">submit</a>
```